# How can I write and append using echo command to a file

Tags: shell, scripting

I am trying to write a script which will use echo and write/append to a file.
But I have " " in syntax already in strings .. say ..

```
echo "I am "Finding" difficult to write this to file" > file.txt
echo "I can "write" without double quotes" >> file.txt
```

Can anyone please help to understand this, really appreciated.

BR,
SM

Answer (score 73, accepted):

If you want to have quotes, then you must escape them using the backslash character.

```
echo "I am \"Finding\" difficult to write this to file" > file.txt
echo "I can \"write\" without double quotes" >> file.txt
```

The same holds true if you i.e. also want to write the `\` itself, as it may cause side effects. So you have to use `\\`

Another option would be to use The `''  instead of quotes.

```
echo 'I am "Finding" difficult to write this to file' > file.txt
echo 'I can "write" without double quotes' >> file.txt
```

However in this case variable substition doesn't work, so if you want to use variables you have to put them outside.

```
echo "This is a test to write $PATH in my file" >> file.txt
echo 'This is a test to write '"$PATH"' in my file' >> file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your help . Earlier I forgot to told about single quote. Yes, I tried single quote and that worked for me but not fulfill the purpose . Trying using escape backslash character .. Thanks, SM

Comment: Thanks Guys, Using Backslash it is done now ,, and also fulfill my purpose . You guys just awesome . Regards, SM

Comment: it doesn't work for me! ```echo "This is a test to write $PATH in my file" >> file.txt  
echo 'This is a test to write '"$PATH"' in my file" >> file.txt ```

Comment: why is there a second ```echo``` at the end of the first example? I think this is not needed.

Comment: @Sebastian I sure dont know how this got there. In the editing history its not there. I removed it now.

Answer (score 34):

If you have special characters, you can escape them with a backslash to use them as needed:

```
echo "I am \"Finding\" difficult to write this to file" > file.txt
echo "I can \"write\" without double quotes" >> file.txt
```

However, you can also use the shell's "EOF" feature with the `tee` command, which is really nice for writing all sorts of things:

```
tee -a file.txt <<EOF

I am "Finding" difficult to write this to file
I can "write" without double quotes
EOF
```

That will write virtually ANY content you want directly to that file, and escape any special characters until you get to the `EOF`.

*Edited to add the append switch, to prevent overwriting the file:
    `-a`

Comment: Great answer. I improved the answer but I wasnt logged in. It was the addition of the `-a` switch to prevent overwrite.

Comment: tee just saved me a lot of manual shell time...looking to turn this into an ansible playbook with some additional vars to scale it out, thanks!

Comment: nice. but it would have been useful to tell the difference between `> file.txt` and `>> file.txt`: 

`> file.txt`: overwrites the context of the file with the new text 
 `>> file.txt`:  pushes the new text to existing context

Comment: Good solution.  From what I can see though, you cannot have commands interspersed within the EOF to EOF block.  You may want to write a line, execute a command, then write another line and so on.