# What is the difference between ">" and ">>" when using echo to write to file

Tags: linux, file, echo

Followup question when I saw this question [How can I write and append using echo command to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17189237/2039735)

I tried to find it should've been answered but apparently either it's not there or I couldn't find it.

I'm really new to posting question on this website (this is my first one!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`>` is "overwrite", `>>` is "append". The former will overwrite the file, the latter will add to the end.

```
echo foo > file
echo bar > file
cat file
# => bar

echo foo > file
echo bar >> file
cat file
# => foo
#    bar
```

Comment: I knew that using > will create a new file, just found out that using >> also does! great!